# Using Symfony CssSelector, how to ignore hidden elements

Tags: php, html, symfony, css-selectors

I'm using [Symphony CssSelector](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html) and [Symphony DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html).

Below are a couple of examples of what I'm trying to select. The problem I run into is that the page will sometimes throw an element in there with `style="display:none"` and sometimes it doesn't wrap everything with a `span` tag. I want to get everything that is between in the `span class="moreselect"` but only the parts that are not hidden.

Example A:

```
<span class="selectme">
    <p>
        <span class="moreselect">
            This is
            <span>a string</span>
            <span style"display:none">hidden</span>
            <span>that isn't hidden</span>
        </span>
    </p>
</span>
```

Example B:

```
<span class="selectme">
    <p>
        <span class="moreselect">
            This is
            <span>a string</span>
            that isn't hidden
        </span>
    </p>
</span>
```

Here is what I've tried so far.

```
$html->filter('.selectme .moreselect')->text();
// Example A Results: This is a string hidden that isn't hidden
// Example B Results: This is a string that isn't hidden

$html->filter('.selectme .moreselect span')->each(function($node) { echo $node->text(); });
// Example A Results: a string hidden that isn't hidden
// Example B Results: a string
```

Either way, what I'd like as the end result for either example or combination of would be: `This is a string that isn't hidden`

I see there is a `reduce()` method but my attempts at using that haven't been successful. I end up with an `\InvalidArgumentException`.

```
$html->filter('.selectme .moreselect')->reduce(function($node)
{
    if($node->attr('style') == 'display:none') {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
})->each(function($node) { echo $node->text(); });
```

Comment: Does the application always emit those span tags in the form of `<span style="display:none">`? If so, you *could* try selecting (or excluding in this case) by that style attribute value...

Comment: It does, I've tried using the reduce method that's available but what I'm doing doesn't work.